# Method what returns the string of ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

So I have:

```
private static ArrayList<AbstractAnalyser> analysers = new ArrayList<>();

public static String getAnalyser(String analyser){
    if(analysers.contains(analyser)){
      return "The full name of the analyser";
    }
    return null;
}
```

So what I want is..

If the the arraylist contains the parameter analyser, I want it to return the full name of the  object what is in the arraylist.

Let's say these values are in the arraylist:

analyser, method and second. <- random names

If the parameter is analyser and the arraylist contains analyser. The method needs the return that name.

Even when the parameter is "analy".

Comment: we need to see the `AbstractAnalyser` class in order to help you out here...

Comment: How can the parameter be "analyser" and "analy" at the same time?  This question makes little sense.  Sounds like you might want a regular expression to match names.

Comment: Does the `AbstractAnalyser` have something like `getName()` method ?

Comment: @duffymo: Sounds like he wants a substring search. His list contains `AbstractAnalyser` elements, he is using `contains()` with a `String` parameter, though...

Comment: I just want to know when the ArrayList has the three values (look question) and then this method I gave to check if the parameter contains any of the arraylist, if so.. return the name of the the arraylist which contains the parameter.

Comment: @jlordo, agreed.  Sounds like s/he'll have to iterate over the keys and do the substring search instead of contains.

Comment: Since `analysers` is a list of `AbstractAnalyser` objects, it will never "contain" a `String analyser` at all...

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Map instead of a List:

```
private static Map<String, AbstractAnalyser> analysers = new HashMap<>();

public static AbstractAnalyser getAnalyser(String analyserName){
    AbstractAnalyser result = null;
    if ((analyserName != null) && (analyserName.trim().length() > 0)) {
        if (analysers.containsKey(analyserName)) {
            result = analysers.get(analyserName);
        } else {
            for (String key : analysers.keySet()) {
                // put the logic to find the one you want here.       
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, if you must, you can do it this way if the AbstractAnalyser has a way to give you its name:

```
private static List<AbstractAnalyser> analysers = new ArrayList<>();

public static AbstractAnalyser getAnalyser(String analyserName){
    AbstractAnalyser result = null;
    if ((analyserName != null) && (analyserName.trim().length() > 0)) {
        for (AbstractAnalyser analyser : analysers) {
            // Here's how you look by name
            if (analyser.getName().equals(analyserName)) {  
                result = analyser;
                break;    
            } else {
               // put special logic to find the one you want here. 
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using the Map is always more efficient when you give the exact name because the lookup is `O(1)`.  The List lookup is always `O(N)`.

Comment: You should have your `for` in an `else` block.

Comment: just noticed it. fixed.  i saved it when your very good comment came up.  thank you, ravi.

Comment: I have done everything in an ArrayList, would this be possible in ArrayList? (Instead of (Hash)Map)

Comment: don't try to do some tricks to keep using ArrayList while you should actually use a map. You should choose the right class to store your elements that fits your needs.

Comment: I would prefer a Map as well, bobkilla.  But I wouldn't consider the code that I posted using a List to be "tricky".  It's just a choice as to whether the name key is internal or external to the value.

Comment: I was talking to user2192658 ;) I agree with everything you said on your answer.